# HMENU only pages with a specific value in custom field

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a custom field (lets say its named myfield) in the table pages with the values 0, 1 or 2. I now want to create a HMENU for all pages that have a specific value (for example all pages with myfield=1) in this field.

How could I get this?

As far as I know I can not add a where-clause to the HMENU. So will I need a USER_INT for it?

Will it work somehow like this:

```
includeLibs.something = mypath/user_myclass.php
lib.servicenav = HMENU
lib.servicenav {
  special = list
  special.value = USER
  special.value.userFunc = user_myclass->myFunction
  special.value.myfieldvalue = 1 # 0, 1, or 3
}
```

user_myclass.php->myFunction:

```
function myFunction($a, $myfieldvalue) {
  // - search all pages with $myfieldvalue
  // - add all pids of this page to the returnvalue (as string)
  $returnvalue = "5, 19, 200";
  return $returnvalue;
}
```

Will this solution work? Are there better solutions?

### Edit: cascavals solution:

It works in a small testproject with this:

```
lib.menu = HMENU
lib.menu{
special = list
special.value.cObject = CONTENT
  special.value.cObject {
    table = pages
    select {
      where = myfield=0
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
      field = uid
      wrap = |,
    }
  }
entrylevel = 1
1 = TMENU
1.NO = 1
1.NO.linkWrap =
<div class="menu">|</div>
überschreibt
2 < .1
2.NO.linkWrap =
<div class="menu-ebene2">|</div>
```

But it does not work in a bigger project with this (I get no output):
*Also when I copy the Menu from above it does not work in this project..*

```
lib.navigation = HMENU
lib.navigation {
special = list
special.value.cObject = CONTENT
  special.value.cObject {
    table = pages
    select {
      where = myfield=0
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
      field = uid
      wrap = |,
    }
  }
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        noBlur = 1
        expAll = 0
        wrap = <ul class="nav1">|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li class="last">|</li>
            altText = subtitle // title
            title = subtitle // title
        }

        CUR < .NO
        CUR.ATagParams = class="active"
        CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current first">|</li> |*| <li class="current">|</li> |*| <li class="current last">|</li>

        ACT < .CUR
        ACT = 1
        ACT.ATagParams = class="active"


    }
    2 = TMENU
    2 < .1
    2 {
        expAll = 0
        wrap = <ul class="nav2">|</ul>
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As `special.value` has `stdWrap`, you can still select page UIDs dynamically and create a comma-separated list that is expected:

```
lib.servicenav = HMENU
lib.servicenav {
  special = list
  special.value.cObject = CONTENT
  special.value.cObject {
    table = pages
    select {
      pidInList = [UID of the root page of your website]
      recursive = 99
      where = myfield=1
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
      field = uid
      wrap = |,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The idea is good (and my question about the comma-seperated list was stupid, sure it will be a comma-list with this wrap). It works in a small test project. But not in a bigger project where I want to implement it

Comment: I added the both examples where it works and where not. Do you see why it does not work in the 2ed example?

Comment: Updated my post again. It does not matter if I take the example from my testproject into the real project. It only output the "Home" link, nothing more. Any idea what I could check?

Comment: So it works in one test project but not in the other one? 1. Test the menu in the second project that it displays when you insert manual list of items. 2. Make sure you have items which match the `where` condition. 3. Clear TYPO3 cache.

Comment: Yes, in the where clause I have now: `where = 1=1` (or don't add it at all) but I only get 1 UID (its a subpage from the home, thats why I only see the "home" link. I overwrote the hole lib.naviation too see what UIDs I get: lib.navigation = CONTENT
  lib.navigation {
    table = pages

    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
      field = uid
      wrap = |,
    }
  }

Comment: I found something new: In the project the root page is just a link to "home". And with the CONTENT table = pages I get only all pages under "home". So if I add more subpages under "home" I get this uids too. I now need something like to say he have to search for all uids under the root page, not under the "home". Hope you understand

Comment: 1. Test what happens when you set `special.value = [UIDs]` instead of my code. 2. I updated my code - see the `pidInList` and `recursive` properties. I think `pidInList` gets populated by default by the current page UID so this might be screwing up the select.

Comment: The `special.value = [uis]` works, I have already try this. The Problem realy is in the CONTENT element. The recursive in the select don't change anything. Right now I test slide = -1 and slide.collect = -1. Anyway i give you +1 and will accept your answer when we found a final solution

Comment: Hmm, strange. Remember that you have to use both `pidInList` (set to 0 so that it really starts from the root) AND `recursive`. You can take the whole `CONTENT` code out of the `HMENU` and let it be displayed in some part of the page so that you know what it returns and thus what is actually being used for `special.value`.

Comment: I think I understand now how CONTENT works. In the testproject it also not working when I am on a subpage. A problem will be to display the first level all times and the second level only from the current page. I will give it a new try tomorrow.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to set `pidInList` to the root of your web (UID 1?) instead of the absolute root (UID 0). It really seems to me to be the cause of the problem because by default it's set to `this`.

Comment: when I set pidInList = 3 (my root) with recursive = 99 I get ALL (also all subpages) in the 1. level navigation. With only pidInList = 3 it looks better! But the where clause is not working (also pages without myfield=0 are shown)

Comment: OK, I've just tested it as well and it didn't work either with `pidInList = 0`. It really must be the website root. It's correct that all the subpages are returned because it's the `where` clause that should further restrict it only to pages you want. If there's nothing returned when `where` is used, then I think your `where` clause is wrong.

Comment: Also check that... 1. You are using the right database field. 2. Those pages really have "0" set in the database and not `null` or empty string. 3. The pages don't have "hide in menu" set. 4. The pages are not disabled or with start time in future or end time in past (the `select` won't return such pages by default and it cannot be changed).